# Typescript inference with repeated generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Basically, why does Typescript's inference not generate an error in the second example here:

```
type MyType<TRecord extends Record<string,any>> = {
    rec: TRecord
    rec2: TRecord
}

const myRec = { idFoo: 3 } 

function createMyType<T extends MyType<Record<string,any>>>(obj: T):T {
    return obj
}

const myType = createMyType({
    rec: myRec,
    rec2: 3, // <-- error here as expected
})

const myType2 = createMyType({
    rec: myRec,
    rec2: {}, // <-- no error here
})
```

In other words, why doesn't it realize that the generic parameter in `createMyType` doesn't actually satisfy the constraint because `rec` and `rec2` aren't the same type?  Or am I misunderstanding how the inference here is working (probably).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq4IB54CUIGMD2AnAJlBAB7AQB2+AzlBjgclcLgJbkDmANAIbkgB8-KAF4oAbwCwAKCiyouLAC4o6LHnzS58rACZlq+hqkBfadJzkmUALYg6I8VBb4AYtmzKAzFGNQzUgDMAV3JMYBZscihMBW4yOERIVCJSCmpYBCRkOnVGZjYuXgFBAApsACMAK30ASkV4cU05BWAg3CiKyulTKXNIq1tE6FEYiDiIBKQSyRlmpRs7LE4m2QVMPShPTigAeh2oZABaQ6JcXDwoAAsIBShuGhJIMIgjYxr-CwHMyB0HUfHJpBpittJhlLY6MtZqtdMoxMZtnsDscoORsKdzrgrjcIN0akA)

### Clarification

Another way to ask this might be -- how can I type `MyType` or `createMyType` so that an error is noted in the second example because `rec` and `rec2` are not the same type (`TRecord`)?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? because `{}` does fulfill the type `Record<string, any>`

Comment: true, but in `createMyType` the generic `T` is constrained to `MyType` and and I don't understand how a given type of `MyType` can be satisfied by a type where `rec` and `rec2` are not both the same type, i.e. `TRecord`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is where you are scoping `T`. Try this, where `T` is set to the common type instead of the overall type:

```
function createMyType<T extends Record<string,any>>(obj: MyType<T>): MyType<T> {
    return obj
}
```

In your previous example, `T` is valid if it extends the contract `{rec: Record<string, any>, rec2: Record<string, any>}`. Well, `{rec: {idFoo: number}, rec2: {}}` **does** satisfy that contract.

With this change both uses will error.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the non-strict mode?

(This setting is defined in the  tsconfig.json file)

Comment: No.  Strict mode is on.  I edited the question to add a playground showing that.